# Looking for a formula to represent the sequence $2,4,2,8,2,4,2,16,2,4,2,8,\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a formula with which I can represent the sequence $2,4,2,8,2,4,2,16,2,4,2,8,\dots$?

Comment: There are infinitely many sequences starting with these values.

Comment: Also when you say equation, I am unsure what you mean. You mean recursive sequence? We can see that $2\to 4,2\to8,2\to16$ so clearly this isn't an equation.

Comment: $a_n=2$ raised to the power of $[1$+number of zeros at the end of the binary representation of $n]$.

Comment: I have edited your question, but you're probably going to add some more contents to it (for example, describe the background of this problem, where does it originate from, what have you tried so far, etc).

Comment: +1 to @barakmanos, as the question already has a very good answer.  I vote to reopen as well.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Thanks, but the actual answer that I gave is one comment above the one that you up-voted.

Comment: In the `C` programming language: `u[n] =  (n ^ (n-1)) + 1`

Comment: @barakmanos I was actually referring to Travis's answer, which is a hint leading to pretty much your conclusion.  I see your actual answer just came through, which I'll upvote.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P_n$ denote the number of zeros at the end of the binary representation of $n$.

Note that $P_n$ also gives the number of times that $n$ is divisible by $2$.

Your sequence can be represented as: $$a_n=2^{P_n+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

Go to oeis.org  (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences)

Put 2,4,2,8,2,4,2,16,2,4,2,8 into the box

click the "Search" button

get two different named sequences that contain this:

A209675, the Radon function at even positions

A171977, a(n) = 2^(k+1) where 2^k is the highest power of 2 dividing n

An added bonus: this will often give you additional properties, references, and remarks about the sequence

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the prime factorizations of the even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

you can also look it up here. You just need to enter enough terms of your sequence. If you don't find it, it may mean that it is a new sequence ( or that it shares few terms with some other sequence ).

https://oeis.org/

and here it is:

https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C4%2C2%2C8%2C2%2C4%2C2%2C16%2C2%2C4%2C2%2C8%2C...&language=english&go=Search